# How to read an array in application.ini in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config

How to read an array declared in the application.ini file using zend_config object.

eg 1 : 
supported.prop[]="abc"
supported.prop[]="def"

when I say $config->supported->prop, it returns zend_config object, while I was expecting an array to be returned.

eg 2: 
supported.prop="abc"
This is straightforward though, where you say $config->supported->prop gives string "abc".

So, can someone help me with the eg 1 , where I am trying to read the array with zend_config object.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$config->supported->prop->toArray() will givie you an array.

Answer (score 3):

`Zend_Config` implements the [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and [Countable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interfaces, so you can interact with an instance just like you would an array:

```
foreach ($config->supported->prop as $v){
    echo $v;
}

$count = count($config->supported->prop);
```

Comment: I was looking for some sort of straightforward method that does it. Seems like this is the only way. Thanks for the answer